# Draw Contours in opencv around recognized polygon

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour, object-recognition

I am working on OpenCV-Python.
I have a image like this(bellow image,but without light green lines) from live feed by webcam.I have found corners coordinates,

```
(array([[[280, 109]],

   [[162, 206]],

   [[189, 341]],

   [[329, 389]],

   [[444, 283]],

   [[412, 160]]])
```

of polygon.
How to draw a line around recognized polygon like light green lines shown on image?

[image: Recognized shape]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `drawContours()` function:

```
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```

The documentation explains it well:

http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Result is like this,It can't draw lines.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B53F0wBGnYhdTFN1U0tQQzM3QTg/view?usp=sharing

What can I do for this?

Comment: I found a solution,I think It's my fault,

`cv2.drawContours(img,[contours],-1,(0,255,0),3)`

This is working properly.Thanks @Mahm00d